# On iOS 13, AVPlayer chooses an audio only stream for this HLS video. Can I control this behavior, and instead have it load the video + audio?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, ios13, avplayerviewcontroller

An HLS/m3u8 video file (that I don't control) has an option to provide a audio-only stream, presumably for poor network conditions. On iOS 13 this gets selected all the time, even when the network's not that bad. On iOS 12 and earlier it would always select the proper stream with audio AND video.

Here's the video file: https://v.redd.it/gl3chx2kd4v31/HLSPlaylist.m3u8

Is there a way under iOS 13 to tell it PLEASE select the video stream as well, not just the audio one? So users can actually watch the video?

Answer (score 0):

That link should work in safari on Desktop, but it's actually downloading the manifest. I think you should fix the content-type: